# How to use loops to avoid repeating the same operation for each index in your arrays?

Tags: python, atom-editor

I am new to python and I am not very clear on loops. I want to learn how to change my if statements to loops as they are very long. Does anyone know how to do this? Please understand that I can't show the full code due to personal reasons.

```py
transaction_category = [2000, 2500, 5000, 15000, 30000] 
first_50k_1_category_rates = [0.05, 1.55, 1.85, 1.90, 2.00, 2.08] 
first_50k_2_categories_or_more_rates = [0.05, 1.80, 2.00, 2.20, 2.30, 3.50]

if (count == 1) and (account_balance <= 50000):
    if (total_eligible_monthly_transactions < transaction_category[0]):
        annual_interest_rate1 = first_50k_1_category_rates[0] 
    elif (transaction_category[0] <= total_eligible_monthly_transactions < transaction_category[1]):
        annual_interest_rate1 = first_50k_1_category_rates[1]
    elif (transaction_category[1] <= total_eligible_monthly_transactions < transaction_category[2]):
        annual_interest_rate1 = first_50k_1_category_rates[2]
    elif (transaction_category[2] <= total_eligible_monthly_transactions < transaction_category[3]):
        annual_interest_rate1 = first_50k_1_category_rates[3]
    elif (transaction_category[3] <= total_eligible_monthly_transactions < transaction_category[4]):
        annual_interest_rate1 = first_50k_1_category_rates[4]
    else:
        if (total_eligible_monthly_transactions >= transaction_category[4]):
            annual_interest_rate1 = first_50k_1_category_rates[5]
```

Comment: I suggest you look at some python tutorials online first, e.g.: https://www.learnpython.org/en/Loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use for loop!

You can call "break" in the loop when you have find correct case.

Note that transaction_category[0] <= total_eligible_monthly_transactions is always True, if total_eligible_monthly_transactions < transaction_category[0] is False. So you do not need to test: transaction_category[0] <= total_eligible_monthly_transactions